# How to distinguish action-buttons in ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am using ember.js and bootstrap for my page.

I am having two buttons in my modal, where two different actions needs to be done based on the value of the button like approve action and decline action

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="decline" {{action "pendingAction" selectedRow target="controller" }}>Decline</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="approve" {{action "pendingAction" selectedRow target="controller"}}>Approve</button>
```

Now i wanted to get the value of the button on which user clicked in the controller

```
App.ApprovalrequestsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    pendingAction:function(){

//get the clicked button value here,  so that i can do different tasks 
based on the value of button

  }
}
});
```

now i want to get the clicked button value inside actions in the controller,  so that i can do different tasks.. can anyone please help am a newbie.

Comment: You can pass parameters to the function from the action - is this what you mean? See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_additional-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in an argument that differentiates the buttons. Your new actions would be:

```
{{action "pendingAction" "decline" selectedRow target="controller" }}
{{action "pendingAction" "approve" selectedRow target="controller" }}
```

Then in your handler:

```
pendingAction: function(action, selectedRow) {
    switch(action) {
        case 'approve':
            // approve
            break;
        case 'decline':
            // decline
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example http://jsbin.com/nasatupu/1/edit

You can add parameters to {{action}} like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="approve" {{action "pendingAction"  "param1" selectedRow target="controller" value="approve" }}>Approve</button>
```